# The correct way to implement an animation loop in CImg

Tags: c++, cimg

I am trying to use CImg to visualize my program. I don't want to use OpenGL because I am trying to write a small rendering engine(Just for my own interest, not an assignment!!!).

I want to create an animation loop in CImg.

This is my loop.

```
while (!disp.is_closed() && !disp.is_keyQ() && !disp.is_keyESC()) {

    img.fill(0);                           // Set pixel values to 0 (color : black)
    img.draw_text(t%WIDTH,30,"Hello World",purple); // Draw a purple "Hello world" at coordinates (100,100).

    img.draw_text(10,10, ( "Time used for rendering :: " + std::to_string( 1.0 / ( duration.count()/cnt/1000000.0 ) ) ).c_str(), purple);

    disp.render(img);
    disp.paint();

    if (t % (int)cnt == 0) {
        tmp = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(tmp - start);
        start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    }
    t++;

}
```

It works OK but the framerate is highly unstable(ranging from 100fps to 380 fps). Is this normal? Or, is this the right way to construct an animation loop in CImg?

I read the documentation of CImg and it said

> Should not be used for common CImgDisplay uses, since display() is more useful.

But when I put it like this,

```
while (!disp.is_closed() && !disp.is_keyQ() && !disp.is_keyESC()) {

    img.fill(0);                           // Set pixel values to 0 (color : black)
    img.draw_text(t%WIDTH,30,"Hello World",purple); // Draw a purple "Hello world" at coordinates (100,100).

    img.draw_text(10,10, ( "Time used for rendering :: " + std::to_string( 1.0 / ( duration.count()/cnt/1000000.0 ) ) ).c_str(), purple);

    disp.display(img);

    if (t % (int)cnt == 0) {
        tmp = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(tmp - start);
        start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    }
    t++;

}
```

This FPS drops to 11. So, what has gone wrong?

Thanks in advance.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ I am a line ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Edit 1 :

```
    //
    //  main.cpp
    //  Render Engine
    //
    //  Created by Ip Daniel on 6/4/18.
    //  Copyright © 2018 Ip Daniel. All rights reserved.
    //

    #include "CImg.h"
    #include <chrono>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace cimg_library;

    #define WIDTH 640
    #define HEIGHT 480

    time_t start_time;
    time_t tmp;
    double time_passed = 0;

    int main() {

        CImg<unsigned char> img(WIDTH,HEIGHT,1,3);  // Define a 640x400 color image with 8 bits per color component.
        CImgDisplay disp(img,"My Hello World Loop");
        unsigned int t = 0;
        double cnt = 30;

        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto tmp = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(tmp - start);

        unsigned char purple[] = { 255,0,255 };        // Define a purple color

        while (!disp.is_closed() && !disp.is_keyQ() && !disp.is_keyESC()) {

            img.fill(0);                           // Set pixel values to 0 (color : black)
            img.draw_text(t%WIDTH,30,"Hello World",purple); // Draw a purple "Hello world" at coordinates (100,100).

            img.draw_text(10,10, ( "Time used for rendering :: " + std::to_string( 1.0 / ( duration.count()/cnt/1000000.0 ) ) ).c_str(), purple);

    //      disp.display(img);

            disp.render(img);
            disp.paint();

            if (t % (int)cnt == 0) {
                tmp = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
                duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(tmp - start);
                start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            }


            t++;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

The command to compile is

> g++ -o main main.cpp -O2 -lm -lpthread -I/usr/X11R6/include -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lm -lpthread -lX11

Comment: Your x position of your text increases with every frame until it reaches the edge and starts over. Is it possible that you're getting the highest framerate when the text is near the edge and is getting clipped by the boundary? That would allow the image rendering to skip writing several pixels and speed up.

Comment: I guess no because I didn't use t to calculate the framerate.

Comment: Please show your complete code... https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and also state your OS and how you compiled it. It makes assistance simpler.

Comment: Edited. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for adding your code and environment. I have been experimenting with your code and I am not sure I really understand what the issue is - whether it is the variation in render times or something else. Anyway, it is a bit much for a comment so I have made an answer and folks can maybe then discuss it.

Basically, I don't really think it is that reasonable to expect a program that interacts with an X11 server, on a multi-user operating system to be that deterministic - and, secondly, I am also not sure it matters.

I changed your code a little to measure the time for 100 frames, and on my machine it varies between 20,000 microseconds and 150,000 microseconds with the average being fairly consistently around 80,000 microseconds. So that is an average of 80ms for 100 frames, or 0.8ms per frame, and a range of 0.2-1.5ms per frame.

For a smooth animation, you are going to want 25-30 fps which is 33-40ms per frame. So your render time is around 0.8ms incurred once every 30ms, or around 2-3% of your frame time, and only 5% worst case (1.5ms on a 30ms frame).

So, I think your code is more likely to have the frame it needs and be able to wait/sleep 24ms on average before needing to render it, so you will have plenty of time in hand and a 0.8-1.5ms variation in a 30ms frame rate will not be noticeable.